# Is it safe to use the mac's cable for an airport express?

Tags: airport, power

When you pull the power plug off the airport express, a connector appears, similar to the connector on the mac's power brick. These connect perfectly, but I want to be sure: is it safe to use a mac's cable to power an airport express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use the smaller Airport cable to power the Mac power adapter without having a ground and you can safely do the opposite as long as you get a firm connection and support the AirPort hardware if the plug extends lower than the bottom of the device.

Comment: What do you mean by "if the plug extends lower than the bottom of the device"?

Comment: Perhaps if you [have it like this](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s6/sh/9f236b66-7fdc-4482-85b1-eec3cf0463d9/0250b053c7151361afb3388cd8bb06a2/res/989de971-46b7-46be-bc4c-8fb42404bc0c/skitch.png)?

Comment: Link is inaccessible.

Comment: @firefly - Not sure why you don't get the other link - how about this one? http://i.stack.imgur.com/hePCZ.jpg

Comment: Yeah, the Evernote link just gives me this: http://i.imgur.com/agGFLPm.png   I see what you mean now though, thanks.